# LWC is it possible to open Community standard Messages component modal with predefined user field?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, partner-communities, direct-messaging

Is it possible to open a standard Direct Messages component with a predefined user field from the custom button as it is done once you click on the tagged user in the Feed Item?

> Hover on tagged user

[image]

> Click Message button

[image]

There are no additional params in the URL once modal opened. So, it should be a standard lightning action.
Can it be called from the custom method in LWC?

For now, I am just redirecting the user to Direct Messages page once a user clicks a custom button.

The URL is:

> /<comm_name>/s/messages/Home

[image]

> Direct Messages page:

[image]

Initially, the page will be empty and the user has to click New to open standard modal and enter User and Subject.

I look for a way to open that modal component if that`s possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an internal event used by Salesforce but it can change anytime so I wouldn't recommend using it in production. I will see if I have details somewhere.

Comment: @manjit5190, thx for the update.

Comment: Just curious if anyone ever had an answer for this.

Comment: @SteveSchrab unfortunately, not.